# Django custom user not having password column, which is expected to have been inherited from AbstractUser

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-custom-user

I am a beginner trying to learn to program in django. I have begun my first website.

All I want as of now is a registration form (and a login form) to create accounts and for those accounts to be stored on a database.

Here is the directory structure of my project:

[image: Directory Structure]

I have created a custom user class, and not defined any column called 'password'. If I was subclassing models.Model or something, I would expect it to throw a 'no such column' error. However, django's default user class has a password column and I am inheriting from it y subclassing AbstractUser, right?

This is my `models.py` for reference:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

import datetime

from django_countries.fields import CountryField

# Create your models here.

class UserProfile(AbstractUser):

    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length = 16, unique = True, blank = False, null = False)
    country = CountryField()
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(max_length = 8, blank = False, null = True)
    sex = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('sex'),
                                              choices = ((1, _('Male')), (2, _('Female')),)
                                              )
    USERNAME_FIELD = "phone_number"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['country', 'date_of_birth', 'sex']
```

Code to my `forms.py`:

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import UserProfile
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from django.forms.widgets import DateInput


# Create your forms here..

class NewUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    phone_number = forms.RegexField(max_length = 16, regex = r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$')
    country = CountryField()
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField()
    sex = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
                                      choices = ((1, _('Male')), (2, _('Female')),),
                                      widget = forms.RadioSelect,
                                     )
    
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ("phone_number", "date_of_birth", "country", "sex", "password1", "password2")
        widgets = {
            'date_of_birth': DateInput()
            }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password1'].help_text = None
        self.fields['password2'].help_text = None
    
    def save(self, commit = True):
        user = super(NewUserForm, self).save(commit = False)
        user.phone_number = self.cleaned_data['phone_number']
        user.username = user.phone_number
        user.country = self.cleaned_data['country']
        user.date_of_birth = self.cleaned_data['date_of_birth']
        user.sex = self.cleaned_data['sex']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Relevant portion of my 'settings.py`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'inside.apps.InsideConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'phonenumber_field',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'inside.UserProfile'
```

Here is the output upon running `python manage.py runserver`:

```py
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 05, 2022 - 00:17:03
Django version 4.0.1, using settings 'app.settings'  
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[05/Feb/2022 00:17:21] "GET /register HTTP/1.1" 200 12908
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[05/Feb/2022 00:17:22] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2440
[05/Feb/2022 00:17:58] "POST /register HTTP/1.1" 200 12908
[05/Feb/2022 00:18:15] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 301 0
Internal Server Error: /admin/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 416, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: inside_userprofile.password

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 254, in wrapper
    return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 225, in inner
    if not self.has_permission(request):
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 199, in has_permission
    return request.user.is_active and request.user.is_staff
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 248, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 384, in _setup
    self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\middleware.py", line 25, in <lambda>
    request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\middleware.py", line 11, in get_user
    request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 184, in get_user
    user = backend.get_user(user_id)
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\backends.py", line 156, in get_user
    user = UserModel._default_manager.get(pk=user_id)
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 435, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 262, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1354, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size) 
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1202, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Kanav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 416, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: inside_userprofile.password
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.
I have wiped out previous migrations and  migrated multiple times before running. It does not work.

Comment: did you migrate properly before running server?

Comment: yes, I did. I ran python manage.py makemigrations inside (inside is the name of my app) and ran python manage.py migrate.